# Summarise and list custom index in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to output grouped summary variables with a corresponding list of identifying variables.

Using the `dplyr::starwars` dataset as an example, I would like to calculate number of characters with "light" skin color, grouped by gender, with a vector of names corresponding to each match in a separate output column.

In the real-world use case, there would be more than one condition to `summarise`, and the unique identifier could be `subjectID`/`studyID`/etc.  I'm open to `data.table` solutions, prefer solutions that are vector based, R Shiny friendly, easily converted to a function.

Example from `dplyr::starwars`:

```
starwars %>% 
  filter(species %in% c("Human", "Droid")) %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarise(
    skin = sum(skin_color=="light", na.rm=T),
    hair = sum(hair_color=="brown", na.rm=T)
  )
```

Desired output:

```
gender skin hair  skinname                                                   hairname
 female  6   6  femname1, femname2, femname3, femname4, femname5, femname6   femhname1, femhname2, femhname3, femhname4, femhname5, femhname6
 male    5   8  mname1, mname2, mname3, mname4, mname5                       mhname1, mhname2, mhname3, mhname4, mhname5, mhname6, mhname7 mhname8
 none    0   0                                                 
 <NA>    0   0
```

This output would then be tranposed using `t()` and would use `paste()` to create a hover-over display of matching names in `DT` (DataTables).

I'm thinking I need something like

```
skinname = as.list(.$name[which(skin_color == "light")])
```

in the `summarise` step, or possibly a custom function with a `do.call` in `summarise`/`mutate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a nested data.frame, you can use `tidyr::nest`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>%
    filter(species %in% c("Human", "Droid"), 
           skin_color == 'light') %>%
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    group_by(skin = n(), add = TRUE) %>% 
    nest(name)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   gender  skin             data
#>    <chr> <int>           <list>
#> 1 female     6 <tibble [6 x 1]>
#> 2   male     5 <tibble [5 x 1]>
```

or if you just want nested vectors, summarize with `list`:

```r
starwars %>%
    filter(species %in% c("Human", "Droid"), 
           skin_color == 'light') %>%
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    summarise(skin = n(),
              name = list(name))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   gender  skin      name
#>    <chr> <int>    <list>
#> 1 female     6 <chr [6]>
#> 2   male     5 <chr [5]>
```

or if you want to keep the empty rows, subset instead of filter:

```r
starwars %>% 
    filter(species %in% c("Human", "Droid")) %>%
    group_by(gender) %>%
    summarise(
        skin = sum(skin_color == "light"), 
        name = list(name[skin_color == 'light'])
    )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   gender  skin      name
#>    <chr> <int>    <list>
#> 1 female     6 <chr [6]>
#> 2   male     5 <chr [5]>
#> 3   none     0 <chr [0]>
#> 4   <NA>     0 <chr [0]>
```

If you want to collapse the names down to a single string `toString` will do the job, but make sure there are no commas in the strings if you plan on separating later.

Comment: Thanks for this, I should have mentioned that the objective is to create a grouped summary table of counts of multiple conditions.  As a result, I think moving `skin_color == light` to the `filter()` step won't work.  I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should be grouping instead of filtering.

Comment: I believe your last option there is the solution I'm looking for, thanks.